# VP ontoUML plugin: how-to add <<relator>> class to <<material>> relation

Tags: plugins, ontology, conceptual-model

Using Visual Pradigm v17, OpenJDK v11.0.10, OntoUML plugin 0.5.3 on MacOS 10.16:

I'd like to use the `relator` class in my model. I cannot find a way to manually connect the `relator` class to the `material` relation that it is supposed to specify.

I tried to draw a connection, just like e.g. a specialisation or association relation, from the `relator` class to the `material` relation. I tried several different options of those that are being presented, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

After muddling with this over an extended period, I feel stupid to see the solution to this.

1. Add an association class *duh* by right-clicking the canvas and selecting *Add Shape* > *Association Class*
2. Select the `mediation` relation that it should specify.
3. Done

I can't believe that I missed this obvious way forward